# Powershell application portable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, portable-executable, portable-applications

Where i can download powershell portable? I know that carl posser create it, but site portablepowershell.com does not work and google don't help me =(. Any body have portable powershell v2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now powershell installed on all actual windows versions:)

Answer (score 0):

Additional you can use [PowerGUI](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/m/bits), and [Executable File from Script](http://documents.software.dell.com/powergui/3.5/user-guide/developing-scripts-in-the-powergui-script-editor/compiling-scripts/executable-file-from-script) to .NET 3.5/4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Powershell Core. It looks portable to me (Tested on a windows 7 embedded without .net framework installed).

[Download Powershell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)

Download the Binaries zip, extract and run pwsh.exe
Keep in mind that there are some differences in code comparing to regular powershell.